# Ceil function: how can we implement it ourselves?

Tags: c++, ceil

I know that C++ provides us with a ceil function. For practice, I was wondering how can we implement the ceil function in C++. The signature of the method is 
public static int ceil(float num)

Please provide some insight.

I thought of a simple way: Convert num to a string, find the index of the decimal point, check if the decimal part is greater than 0. If yes, return num+1 else return num. But I want to avoid using the string conversion

Comment: The signature of [`std::ceil()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/ceil) is not `public static int ceil(float)`.  Beware of Java or C# references that might look like C++ at a quick glance.  Always make sure the reference you consult is for C++.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is a naive implementation for positive numbers (this uses the fact that casting to `(int)` truncates toward zero):

```
int ceil(float num) {
    int inum = (int)num;
    if (num == (float)inum) {
        return inum;
    }
    return inum + 1;
}
```

It is easy to extend this to work with negative numbers too.

Your question asked for a function returning `int`, but normally the `ceil()` function returns the same type as its argument so there are no problems with the range (that is, `float ceil(float num)`). For example, the above function will fail if `num` is 1e20.

Comment: Given that most integers cannot be represented exactly in popular `float` implementations, I doubt this is a reliable way to implement `ceil()`.

Comment: @AndréCaron: That's true, but it shouldn't be a problem for this *particular* implementation, since the input to the function is not an integer.

Comment: I was looking for something simple like your answer

Comment: `inum + 1` should be done only for positive numbers.

Answer (score 33):

You can take apart the ingredients of an IEEE754 floating point number and implement the logic yourself:

```
#include <cstring>

float my_ceil(float f)
{
    unsigned input;
    memcpy(&input, &f, 4);
    int exponent = ((input >> 23) & 255) - 127;
    if (exponent < 0) return (f > 0);
    // small numbers get rounded to 0 or 1, depending on their sign

    int fractional_bits = 23 - exponent;
    if (fractional_bits <= 0) return f;
    // numbers without fractional bits are mapped to themselves

    unsigned integral_mask = 0xffffffff << fractional_bits;
    unsigned output = input & integral_mask;
    // round the number down by masking out the fractional bits

    memcpy(&f, &output, 4);
    if (f > 0 && output != input) ++f;
    // positive numbers need to be rounded up, not down

    return f;
}
```

(Insert the usual "not portable" disclaimer here.)

Comment: You could use `frexp` and `ldexp` to do the extraction and recombination.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: `frexp` returns a float, not an int. How would you propose to mask out the fractional bits then?

Comment: Can't believe yours is not the accepted answer (not to mention the accepted answer is wrong)!

Answer (score 7):

That is essentially what you have to do, but without converting to `string`.

A floating-point number is represented as `(+/-) M * 2^E`.  The exponent, `E`, tells you how far away you are from the binary point<sup>*</sup>.  If `E` is big enough, there is no fractional part, so there's nothing to do.  If `E` is small enough, there is no integer part, so the answer is 1 (assuming `M` is non-zero, and the number is positive).  Otherwise, `E` tells you where the binary point appears within your mantissa, which you can use to do a check, and then perform rounding.

---

<sub>* Not decimal point, because we're in base-2, not base-10.</sub>

Comment: @Charlesworth:yes, I know this fact. I am more concerned with how can i exploit this to determine the decimal part?

Comment: @Time: You can use the `frexp()` function to extract `M` and `E`.  You can then use `E` to identify how many digits in `M` are above the binary point, and how many are below.

Answer (score 5):

My 5 cents:

```
template <typename F>
inline auto ceil(F const f) noexcept
{
  auto const t(std::trunc(f));

  return t + (t < f);
}
```

Comment: Except that's not `constexpr`

Comment: @Anton3 Thanks, it can be made so, if you implement `trunc()` by yourself.

Comment: if you don't care about precision you can just do `const int t = int(f);`

Comment: Oh no, you can't, `f` can be an astronomically large number.

Answer (score 1):

The previous code recommendation:

```
int ceil(float val) 
{
    int temp  = val * 10;
    if(val%10)
    return (temp+1);
    else
    return temp;
}
```

does not compile:  Receives "error C2296: '%': illegal, left operand has type 'float'" on line 4 "if(val%10)" because you can't use the mod operator (%) on a float or double.  See: [Why we can't use operator % for float and double type operands?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17251050/why-we-cant-use-operator-for-float-and-double-type-operands)
It also does not work for decimal values whose precision is not greater than 1/10.

Whereas, the prior code recommendation:

```
int ma_ceil(float num)
{   int a = num;
    if ((float)a != num)
        return num+1;
    return num;
}
```

works well, as long as you don't go beyond the bounds of a floating point value.
num = 555555555;
or 
num = -5.000000001
are not going to work unless you use a double.

Also, because floats and doubles are stored in IEEE floating point format, the binary representations stored can be inexact.  For, instance:

float num = 5;
in some instances might not get the value 5.0000000 assigned, but rather 5.9999998 or 5.00000001.
To correct the prior code version, I'd recommended changing the return value to use integer math rather than relying on the accuracy of the floating point value, as follows:

```
int ma_ceil(float num)
{   int a = num;
    if ((float)a != num)
        return a+1;
    return a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
  double param, fractpart, intpart;

  param = 3.14159265;
  fractpart = modf (param , &intpart);

  int intv = static_cast<int>(intpart); // can overflow - so handle that.

  if (fractpart > some_epsilon)
    ++intv;
```

You just need to define `some_epsilon` value to whatever you want the fractional part to be bigger than before the integer part is incremented. Other things to consider are sign (i.e. if the value is negative etc.)

Comment: I would imagine that you'd want `epsilon` to be 0.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, really? shouldn't it rather be value as close to 0 as possible (say for argument sake 1E-6) to allow for representation issues?

Comment: Isn't that what `std::numeric_limits<float>::epsilon()` is for?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one that works with negative numbers:

```
int ceil(float num) {
    int inum = (int)num;
    if (num < 0 || num == (float)inum) {
        return inum;
    }
    return inum + 1;
}
```

Comment: Hello @aqeel and Welcome to StackOverflow. Did you have a look at the [guidelines of how to answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It will help you a lot avoiding your answer being downvoted. Also, why don't you give some details on how your snippet solves the mentioned problem?

Answer (score 0):

Like so (purely from first principles):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>


template<typename T>
constexpr int truncate( const T val )
{
    return static_cast<int>( val );
}

template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point_v<T>>>
constexpr T modulusFloat( const T divident,
    const T divisor )
{
    return divident - truncate( divident / divisor ) * divisor;
}

template<typename T>
constexpr T modulus( const T divident,
    const T divisor ) noexcept
{
    if constexpr ( std::is_floating_point_v<T> )
    {
        return modulusFloat( divident,
            divisor );
    }
    else
    {
        return divident % divisor;
    }
}

template<typename T>
constexpr T ceil( const T val ) noexcept
{
    return val + (T)1 - modulus( val, (T)1 );
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << ceil( 5.4 ) << '\n';
    std::cout << ceil( -5.4 ) << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

it works with negative value too

```
int ma_ceil(float num)
{   int a = num;
    if ((float)a != num)
        return num+1;

    return num;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

Try this...

```
int ceil(float val)
{
    int temp  = val * 10;
    if(val%10)
    return (temp+1);
    else
    return temp;
}
```

Comment: Needs to be adjusted for -ve values.

Comment: Also, it doesn't deal with e.g. `val = 0.01`.

Comment: @Oli multiply val with 100 if you want check upto two decimal places.

Comment: Right, and then it doesn't handle `0.001`.

Comment: Also, why 10?  Floating-point is in base-2 (at least, IEEE-754 is).

Comment: I was just trying to provide a solution to problem. its all upto the developer what precision he/she wants. And writing "it wont handle 0.0001" if a say "multiply it with 1000", consider that what the user actually considered more about is the value before decimal point in float value.

Comment: But this is not a solution to the problem of "implement `ceil`".