# Why we can't use operator % for float and double type operands?

Tags: c

I am new to C/C++, so I have a couple of questions about a basic type:

1. I have read somewhere that the operator % can't be applied to float or double type operands.
   Then how can I check the divisibility of float or double type variables? I have shown my program with error below:

   ```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main()
   {
       double n,k,t,i;
       int j=0;
       scanf("%f %f",&n,&k);
       i=0;
       while(i<n)
       {
           scanf("%f",&t);
           if(t%k==0)   /* error:invalid operands to binary %  */
               j++;
           i++;
       }
       printf("%d",j);
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. If a positive integer has a range up to 10^9, which qualifier should I use or how to achieve such a large range?

Comment: As for your second question: depending on your compiler, `long int` or `long long int` will give you the range up to 2^63-1 or about 2E9. If you make it `unsigned long long int` you will get al the way to 2^64-1 or 4 billion.

Comment: @Floris do we use format % llu for unsigned long long int ??

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "how can I achieve it". You are using `double` type above. If you decide to use an integer type, then the types that I recommend (`unsigned long long int n, k, t, i;`) would work. A `double` type is big enough to include those numbers without loss of precision - the largest integer that a `double` can hold without loss of precision is 2^53 - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1848700/biggest-integer-that-can-be-stored-in-a-double

Comment: Yes, you would use %llu as the format specifier. `unsigned long long int i;
printf("enter a number: ");
scanf("%llu", &i);
printf("you entered %lld\n", i);
`

Comment: @floris k thnx alot.. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative to the `fmod` answers - which answer the question you originally asked (since you were using `double` type. If, as is clear from your comments, you actually want to use integer types only, you can rewrite your code as follows (with the `unsigned long long int` type to give you plenty of headroom):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()

{

 unsigned long long int n, k, t, i, j=0;

    printf("enter the number of attempts: ");
    scanf("%llu", &n);

    printf("\nEnter the factor: ");
    scanf("%llu", &k);

    i=0;
    while(i<n)
    {
       printf("\nEnter the number to test: ");
       scanf("%llu",&t);
       if(t%k==0) 
         j++;
       i++;
    }
    printf("The number of multiples found was %llu\n", j);
    return 0;
}
```

Note I have attempted to make the I/O a little more descriptive - it is a good idea to prompt the user, rather than just have a blinking cursor waiting for him. Obviously I am guessing at the prompts a bit (may not even be the language you want to use...)

Answer (score 9):

> then how can i check the divisibility of float or double type variables. ??`

Use `fmod`. `%` only work with integer operands. `%` does not work with floating point values because C already provides the `fmod` library function.

Comment: Brief and valuable answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil C committee wrote in C99 Rationale that *The C89 Committee rejected extending the % operator to work on floating types as such usage would duplicate the facility provided by fmod*

Comment: @ouah: Huh, how about that.

Answer (score 4):

Use the function [fmod](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fmod/) and its family.

Answer (score 4):

a. if you want to keep it in floating point, use the `fmod` function from `<math.h>` (`std::fmod` from `<cmath>` in C++).

b. the `int` range is implementation-dependent (although the standard defines a minimum range that, IIRC, should be of +-32767, although on typical machines it will be -2147483648 - 2147483647). If an integer number is in the range of `int` you don't have to do anything particular - an integer literal without suffixes is automatically taken for an `int` if it fits in its range. On the other hand, bigger integer literals may need to be stored in a `long` or `long long` to avoid overflow.

Answer (score 1):

1. `%` can't be used on floats because the standard says so. Use `fmod`. Okay okay okay, the actual *reason* is that the concept of a "remainder" only makes sense for integer division. What `fmod` does is produce an integer quotient for two floating-point arguments:

   ```
   float my_fmod(float a, float b)
   {
       int quot = (int) a/b;
       return a - (quot * b);
   }
   ```
2. If you need a specific range for an integer, don't use `int` with qualifiers since they are implementation-specific. Use a fixed-width type like `uint32_t`.