# Looking for a constexpr ceil function

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, constexpr

Since `std:ceil` is non-`constexpr` neither in Visual Studio 2015, I'm looking for a `constexpr` implementation of it which I can use compile-time - with little success.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See [Ceil function: how can we implement it ourselves?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8378022/369872) it looks like it could be written to be constexpr

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Since the compiler of Visual Studio 2015 still doesn't allow for a constexpr function to have `if` conditionals and variables, I rewrote Jarod42's solution and eliminated them:

```
constexpr int32_t ceil(float num)
{
    return (static_cast<float>(static_cast<int32_t>(num)) == num)
        ? static_cast<int32_t>(num)
        : static_cast<int32_t>(num) + ((num > 0) ? 1 : 0);
}
```

Comment: Just curious. Usually equality comparisons with floating points are frowned upon. Is this an exception?

Comment: @Flip Floating-point comparisons are perfectly okay if you perform them in the right place. In this case we are interested whether the rounded down value equals to the original value (or whether its sign is positive or negative), and since there is no floating-point error in rounding, it is a right place for floating-point equality. If you want to address floating-point errors coming from previous calculations, then you need to modify this function to handle this.

Comment: I used this in my (GPL3) library, hope that is ok ;).

Comment: @CarloWood Sure, thanks for mentioning. What's the name of the library? I'm just curious.

Answer (score 7):

You may use

```
constexpr std::int32_t ceil(float num) {
    std::int32_t inum = static_cast<std::int32_t>(num);
    if (num == static_cast<float>(inum)) {
        return inum;
    }
    return inum + (num > 0 ? 1 : 0);
}
```

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a342afeee8f6a2e3)

Note: Doesn't work once an integer cannot represent float value.

Comment: Why not `float ceil(float);` like the one provided by `std`?

Comment: @legends2k: this implementation doesn't work for all float values, the signature reflect that.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a version building on [Jarod42's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31957574/1417451) by eliminating one of the two branches. This'll work on C++14 or C++17—if you inline the integer cast, you can make it support C++11 as well.

```
constexpr int int_ceil(float f)
{
    const int i = static_cast<int>(f);
    return f > i ? i + 1 : i;
}
```

Here's a small suite to verify the correct behavior. (Just a series of C++17 `static_assert()`s, since the function is `constexpr`—if it compiles, you know the tests passed!)

```
static_assert(int_ceil(0.0) == 0);
static_assert(int_ceil(0.5) == 1);
static_assert(int_ceil(0.999999) == 1);
static_assert(int_ceil(1.0) == 1);
static_assert(int_ceil(123.0) == 123);
static_assert(int_ceil(123.4) == 124);

static_assert(int_ceil(-0.5) == 0);
static_assert(int_ceil(-0.999999) == 0);
static_assert(int_ceil(-1.0) == -1);
static_assert(int_ceil(-123.0) == -123);
static_assert(int_ceil(-123.4) == -123);
```

[Here's a Compiler Explorer sample](https://godbolt.org/z/q1xK1G) to play with (as a bonus, it includes a `constexpr` implementation of `floor()` as well).